# How to calculate and replace values in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists with floating numbers.

lst = [[1.0,2.0,3.0] , [0.0,1.0,2.0] , [1.0,2.0,3.0]]

For each element, I want to find the reciprocal and ignore if == 0.0

No modules please, using lists and loops preferred.

This is all I've come up with:

```
lst = [[1.0,2.0,3.0] , [0.0,1.0,2.0] , [1.0,2.0,3.0]]
new_values=[]
for slist in lst:
        for x in slist:
            if x!=0.0:
                reciprocal=1.0/x
                new_values.append(reciprocal)
            else:
                reciprocal=0.0
                new_values.append(reciprocal)
```

But of course, this just creates a new list, whereas I want it to stay within the list of lists I've written (lst).

Expected

```
lst=[[1/1.0, 1/2.0, 1/3.0] , [1/1.0, 1/2.0] , etc...]]
```

NOTE that the 0.0 I had initially in lst[1] is removed after the calculation.

Comment: `for i` should be `for slist`

Answer (score 5):

Use a list comprehension and overwrite your `lst` variable:

```
lst = [[x if x == 0.0 else 1/x for x in l] for l in lst]
```

<sup>Note that `x == 0.0` is bad practice but I gather that's not the point of this question</sup>

Output:

```
[[1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333], [0.0, 1.0, 0.5], [1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the values in the nested list instead of replacing it with a new list you could do:

```
lst = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0] , [0.0, 1.0, 2.0] , [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]
for slist in lst:
    for i, x in enumerate(slist):
        slist[i] = 1.0 / x if  x != 0.0 else 0.0
print(lst)
# [[1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333], [0.0, 1.0, 0.5], [1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [[1.0,2.0,3.0] , [0.0,1.0,2.0] , [1.0,2.0,3.0]]

def reciprocate(list_input):
    new_list = []
    for x in list_input:
        if x!=0.0:
            new_list.append(1/x)
    return new_list

new_lst = [reciprocate(l) for l in lst]
print(new_lst)
```

This gives the following output.

```
[[1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333], [1.0, 0.5], [1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333]]
```

Comment: I think OP wants to keep `x` if `x==0.0`, so I think you'd need to remove the `continue` and replace it with `new_list.append(x)`.

Comment: If you read the last few lines of his question, he specifically mentioned that he wants to get rid of the element in the list if it is x==0.0. He has also removed that element in the expected output.

Comment: Then in that case, you don't need to do if/else, just do `if x !=  0.0: new_list.append(1/x)`.

Comment: @HS-nebula You're right. Tweaking my code as per your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a nested list in each of the outer iterations.

```
lst = [[1.0,2.0,3.0] , [0.0,1.0,2.0] , [1.0,2.0,3.0]]
new_values=[]
for slist in lst:
    new_sublist = []
    for x in slist:
        if x!=0.0:
            reciprocal=1.0/x
        else:
            reciprocal=0.0
        new_sublist.append(reciprocal)
    new_values.append(new_sublist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comphrensions to achieve the needed:

```
lst = [[1.0,2.0,3.0] , [0.0,1.0,2.0] , [1.0,2.0,3.0]]
reciprocals = [list(map(lambda x: (1/x) if x != 0.0 else 0.0, sub_list)) for sub_list in lst]
```

Outputting:

```
[[1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333], [0, 1.0, 0.5], [1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333]]
```